# Adding the fisheye effect to a d3.layout.tree

Tags: javascript, tree, d3.js, treeview, fisheye

I am pretty new to the d3.js framework. Currently I am working on a d3.layout.tree, very similar to the following example:

http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

Now my question is, is it possible to get the fisheye effect running on the chosen tree layout? I included the following fisheye plugin and followed the instructions:

https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/fisheye

Any ideas or solutions? Thank you for your help!

Comment: You say that you've included the code and followed the instructions. What happened?

Comment: I can't see any changes on the structure. The 'mousemove' listener gets called when I move over a node or a link. The fisheye seems to calculate something but it looks like the values are the same as before the calculation. I have the strong feeling that fisheye is not working because the tree layout gets computed with the  Reingold–Tilford “tidy” algorithm and every node and link has its desired position. Do you see any chance?

Comment: Do you have a complete example somewhere?

Comment: I have uploaded a complete example to the following fiddle url: http://jsfiddle.net/M5Fwm/3/ In this example the circles get scaled but I have no idea how to reposition the links.

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't work for me, I'm getting an error message.

Comment: Sorry about that. This version should work: http://jsfiddle.net/M5Fwm/4/ By the way, you can add new nodes by clicking on existing ones.

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/M5Fwm/5/)?

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! But it is painfully slow and I have no clue why the fisheye is only working when the mouse is directly over a link or a node.

Comment: The event only fires when you move over an element. It certainly can be optimised for performance as well, at the moment it does its computations every time you move the mouse.